# Mongodb Multiple Updates with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm new to Mongodb (using PHP) and being that I'm used to RDMS I have what maybe a newbie question. I have a collection of "pages" that have a field called "tags" in which I have a series of tags, "happy, sad, angry, irtated".

Now I have another collection, called... let's say "users" and I want the user to be able to specify which tags are important to them... so this collection also has a field called "tags" in which I would have maybe, "Happy, and irtated"

Now... here comes the question, let's say I wanted to correct the spelling of irtated in both collections. Normally the RDMS world, I would have referenced these to a single table and then done an innerjoin such that changing the value in one spot would cascade everywhere... Or let say I wanted to remove a tag from the system... say, I didn't want Happy to be used anymore and I wanted to just remove it from all my collections where it exists...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Mongodb instead of RDBMS? most probably you want higher speed. Since in mongodb most related data in one place (in storage devices) so it is easy to retrieve data.That's why we keep same data in different places (Data redundancy). But when it comes to your case you need to keep more time to do the programming to do the same over RDBMS. So both RDBMS and NOSQL have their won pros and cons, and you will never have both profit from one account(Mongodb).